# How to update clang without upgrading to Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, clang, homebrew, macos-mojave

I've just got a MacOS 2 days ago with Mojave 10.14.5 and I was trying to install the latest Clang 12.0.0 but to no avail. I can't upgrade the OS to Catalina, so when I tried the XCode route I could only get the 13.1 version, with LLVM 10.0.1 and Clang-1001.0.46.4.

Then I followed this guide :

https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/24/installing-llvm-clang-on-osx/

which was supposed to help me upgrade the llvm and clang through brew, and I successfully did it.

I got it up to LLVM 11.0.0 (I checked it out through "brew info llvm"), nonetheless when I use the command "clang --version", it still gives me:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang- 
1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix 
InstalledDir:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/u 
sr/bin
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Did I miss something in the brew installation?
2. Is there another way to update to clang without the OS upgrade?

P.s

In the guide I couldn't do from the "Where to find llvm/clang" and downwards, since many of those commands weren't recognized by the terminal

Repost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**homebrew** installs binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, so you normally need to put that at the start of your PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You can check which `clang` will be run when you type `clang` in your Terminal by running:

```
type clang
```

If that tells you `clang` is `/usr/bin/clang` or `/Applications/anything` or `/Library/anything`, that means it is supplied by Apple.

If it contains `/usr/local/anything` or `/opt/anything`, it is probably supplied by **homebrew**.

---

For **hombrew** problems, try asking the good doctor:

```
brew doctor
```